# If I have a character on the screen, how do I make it look in the direction my mouse is pointing?

Tags: xna, c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set sprite to face direction of mouse](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19550/set-sprite-to-face-direction-of-mouse)

I'm drawing a character on the screen, and I would like it so that the character is looking where my mouse is pointing. It's a birds eye view, and the character moves as well. Also any pathfinding collision tutorials would be appreciated

Comment: 2D or 3D? Guess 3D?

Comment: And what do you mean with "pathfinding collision tutorials"? I googled for it and pathfinding seems to be stuff like DFS, BFS or A*. I remember something about vector-surface-cut when you need to solve the problem of where a mouse-pointer shows to in 3D, do you mean that? Somehow the question for the pathfinding does not seem to match the rest of the question at all.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you had

```
Vector2 characterPosition; //on viewport
float characterRotation; //in radians
```

Suppose you also had the current mouse position

```
MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y);
```

Then you could calculate the vector that points from character to mouse position

```
Vector2 dPos = mousePosition - characterPosition;
```

You could then use [`Math.Atan2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2.aspx) to get the angle that this vector forms with positive x axis. That would be the needed angle for the character, so you set it for your characters rotation:

```
characterRotation = (float)Math.Atan2(dPos.Y, dPos.X);
```